# TopLink to EclipseLink migration - Missing class for indicator field value

Tags: eclipselink, toplink

I am migrating Toplink 11g to EclipseLink 12.1.3.  I have EclipseLink.jar to the classpath. I have few mapping xml files. When executing the application, i am getting following error.

Exception [EclipseLink-9005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.SessionLoaderException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while loading the project-xml file [META-INF/Business.xml].
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-43] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Missing class for indicator field value [toplink:object-type-mapping] of type [class java.lang.String].
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping --> [DatabaseTable(attribute-mapping)]).

How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are required to run package renamers etc as described here http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLADG/migrnativetoplink.htm

If you have run the package renamer tools already, search your project.xml file for the toplink:object-type-mapping string which apparently wasn't converted correctly and the logs from running the renaming tool to determine why it wasn't converted.

Comment: i got it. When i ran toplink migration tool on .wmp toplink file, it worked. Thank you.